# My CSS doesn't apply on my HTML file

Tags: html, css

I just started with using html and css, but I already got a problem. I made a html file and a small css file, but when I go into the browser, I only see the html changes.

**HTML:**

```
    <!doctype html>
    
    <html>
      
        <head>
        
            <meta charset="utf-8"> 
            <title> INTAKE </title>
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css" type="text/css"/>
        
        <head>  
    
        <body>
        
            <h1>Intake opdracht</h1>
    
            <p> <strong> <em> 
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, mel te porro eirmod argumentum, has exerci laboramus voluptatibus at. 
            Unum congue legimus sea eu, has no luptatum percipitur. 
            Omnium eleifend voluptatibus has eu. 
            Usu commodo tamquam inermis ei. 
            Elitr aperiri consectetuer at usu, mundi mollis docendi pri et.
            </em> </strong> </p>
    
                <img src="images/html.png"
 onerror="this.src='http://www.moondoggiegraphics.com/html5.png';" width="300"/> 
    
            <p> <i> 
            Soleat facete audiam per eu, sed ex labores tractatos euripidis, quo ut delectus aliquando philosophia. 
            Cum aeque putent ad, amet legere quo in. 
            Inciderint theophrastus qui et, petentium eloquentiam qui te. 
            Nec ad brute nusquam accusam. 
            Duo eu vero commodo, noluisse oportere has ea, at solum debet omnes mea. 
            Mea aperiam bonorum efficiantur eu, te qui alii commodo numquam. 
            </em> </p>
       
                <img src="images/css.png" 
onerror="this.src='http://www.logotypes101.com/logos/194/830812341256B99B32E1A9F242BB9F5F/css3logo.png';"width="200"/>
     
            <p> <i> 
            At per esse eirmod omittam, odio omnis te sed. 
            Id pri graeci prodesset deseruisse, usu etiam eligendi adolescens ut. 
            Ex iudico quodsi vix, id pro exerci ignota, sententiae accommodare mel te. 
            Eos ad nisl velit vitae, vim sonet facilis conceptam et. 
            Eu has intellegam neglegentur, et nam sumo nusquam. Ut ubique luptatum volutpat vim, labitur sapientem mea ea. 
            </em> </p>
     
            <p> <em> 
            Autem saperet cum an. 
            In sit amet harum impetus. 
            Sit ornatus expetendis cu. 
            Nam diceret detraxit intellegam no. 
            </em> </p>
     
                <p> Bron van de <a href= "http://generator.lorem-ipsum.info/"> <b> Lorem ipsum tekst. </b> </a> </p>
    
        </body> 
    
    </html>
```

**CSS:**

```
@charset "utf-8";

p{
    text-align:center;
}

h1{
    background-color:yellow;
    text-align:center; 
}
```

I've added a picture of my folder.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ylc0o.jpg

---

#### Solved

The problem was not my code, it was something on my computer, still don't know what it is, but I tried the code on my laptop and it worked.

Comment: Is `main.css` in the same folder as your html-file? Otherwise you have to change the path.

Comment: are the 2 files in the same folder.

Comment: The css file is called "main.css", not just "main"? Btw you won't see any of the `p {...}` styles (css) - they only affect `<p>...</p>` (html)

Comment: We can help a lot better if you can upload an example to some web server so we can take a look. As it stands all we can do is guess because we do not have enough information.

Comment: Well I don't really understand what information you want, but I tried checking if my css file did load in my browser using Firebug. This was not the case.

Comment: I've added a jsfiddle with your codes above which as you can see is working fine. There must be something wrong with your browser(s) maybe?? lol

Comment: I think my browser is the problem, but I reinstalled it, tried another browser, cleared the cache and it's still not working.. I'm getting a bit frustrated :|

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your css file is linked properly like this:

if css file is in same directory as your html file, then:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css" type="text/css"/>
```

if css file is in a css directory located on the same directory as your html file, then:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css" type="text/css"/>
```

if css file is in a directory one level above your html file, then:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../main.css" type="text/css"/>
```

`../` represents **one directory above** (similar to clicking the `BACK`key while navigating in Windows)

Also, make sure you properly close all tags on your html like this:

```
<html>

    <head>

        <meta charset="utf-8"> 
        <title> INTAKE </title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css" type="text/css"/>

    <head>  

    <body>

        <h1>Intake opdracht</h1>

    <p> <strong> <em> 
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, mel te porro eirmod argumentum, has exerci laboramus voluptatibus at. 
    Unum congue legimus sea eu, has no luptatum percipitur. 
    Omnium eleifend voluptatibus has eu. 
    Usu commodo tamquam inermis ei. 
    Elitr aperiri consectetuer at usu, mundi mollis docendi pri et.
    </em> </strong> </p>

        <img src="images/html.png" onerror="this.src='http://www.moondoggiegraphics.com/html5.png';" width="300"/> 

    <p> <i> 
    Soleat facete audiam per eu, sed ex labores tractatos euripidis, quo ut delectus aliquando philosophia. 
    Cum aeque putent ad, amet legere quo in. 
    Inciderint theophrastus qui et, petentium eloquentiam qui te. 
    Nec ad brute nusquam accusam. 
    Duo eu vero commodo, noluisse oportere has ea, at solum debet omnes mea. 
    Mea aperiam bonorum efficiantur eu, te qui alii commodo numquam. 
    </em> </p>

        <img src="images/css.png" onerror="this.src='http://www.logotypes101.com/logos/194/830812341256B99B32E1A9F242BB9F5F/css3logo.png';"width="200"/>

    <p> <i> 
    At per esse eirmod omittam, odio omnis te sed. 
    Id pri graeci prodesset deseruisse, usu etiam eligendi adolescens ut. 
    Ex iudico quodsi vix, id pro exerci ignota, sententiae accommodare mel te. 
    Eos ad nisl velit vitae, vim sonet facilis conceptam et. 
    Eu has intellegam neglegentur, et nam sumo nusquam. Ut ubique luptatum volutpat vim, labitur sapientem mea ea. 
    </em> </p>

    <p> <em> 
    Autem saperet cum an. 
    In sit amet harum impetus. 
    Sit ornatus expetendis cu. 
    Nam diceret detraxit intellegam no. 
    </em> </p>

        <p> Bron van de <a href= "http://generator.lorem-ipsum.info/"> <b> Lorem ipsum tekst. </b> </a> </p>


    </body>
</html>
```

Here is a jsfiddle with your above codes: https://jsfiddle.net/e0d8my79/37/

Comment: I've added a picture of my folder, maybe that'll help.

Comment: Checked everything, looks like the html is correct.

Comment: Can you copy paste everything in your html as well as everything in your css because the above is working just fine on my end.

Comment: I've added everything in the files.

Comment: That is exactly how I need it, but for some weird reason, am I unable to see it that way.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is in wrong HTML scheme. Make sure `<html>` and `<head>` is properly closed:

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>  

    <body>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Didn't solve, anything, but thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you placed your css link correctly, you may need to delete your browser cache. Just try ctrl+f5.

If that's the case, you had probably defined the css in the html file while the css file was empty, opened the html file in the browser. the browser cached the css file. then you started writing your css, but because the browser has a cached version of the old css file, yo are not able to see your changes.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your href attribute to href=". /main.css".

Answer (score 0):

Please check your extension of the css file.
There will be a change the files is called main.CSS instead of main.css .
You van check this in your FTP program or via the command line on the server.

Answer (score -2):

I just created 2 files with your exact code (one HTML and one CSS file) on my desktop and the css is applying perfectly on it. Have you tried multiple browsers? It is working fine on Google Chrome for me.